# Question regarding multiple dependent drop down lists

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I am currently learning about dependent drop down lists, which is a simple enough concept for me to understand.

What I wanted to know is if it's possible to create two or more lists that are dependent on the same cell, as I don't quite understand if it's possible due to how a singular dependent drop down list is created.

For example, in the image below I wanted to create a situation where if I choose TeamA or TeamB in the Team cell, the only players associatred with that team would show up in the cells Offense and Defense.

[image]

This might be a simple enough question but I couldn't find anything on this, so I appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use helper column (which you can hide later) to create dynamic list:

```
=FILTER(B4:C6,B3:C3=B8)
```

[image]

Refer to array in Data Validation List source:

[image]

Result:

[image]
[image]