# Excel validation not accepting a relative row reference

Tags: excel, list, validation, excel-formula

My goal is to create a list validation that is dependent on what is selected for the cell directly to the left of it.
Here is my formula:
`=OFFSET($I$2,1,MATCH($D2,$I$2:$O$2,0)-1,COUNTA(OFFSET($I$2,1,MATCH($D2,$I$2:$O$2,0)-1,20)),1)`
The problem seems to be with the '$D2'.
Now when I paste this formula directly into the cell it lists out the expected results. If I paste the formula into a below empty cell I can also see the '$D2' change its row value accordingly and I see the expected list of options print out.
[image]

If I copy and paste this into a list data validation I receive an error.
[image]

If I change the relative row reference and make it an absolute cell reference '$D$2' the validation works, but I need each 'Location Section' row to be relative to the 'Object Type' on its' same row. Why would this reference not work as part of a validation?

NOTE: I only have access to a Sharepoint Microsoft 365 version of Excel. I don't have access to Excel options/settings. I've also noticed I don't have access to paste validations.

[image]]

Comment: Excel Data Validation List does not work with dynamic lists.  You will need to put the various lists in named ranges, named the same as the value in column D.  Then use `=INDIRECT($D2)`  Then it will return the values of the named range that matches the value in D2.

Comment: If you have Office 365 or Excel 2021 there may be another solution. What Excel version do you use?

Comment: @P.b. I'm using Office 365 version of Excel.

Comment: @ScottCraner That way also gives me the same error as above. If I do ```=INDIRECT($D$2)``` that works of course. Is being able to use relative references a setting?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's more questions like that on here, but I think this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76558261/12634230

Comment: It works for me: https://imgur.com/a/DVThHN3  I named H2:H4 as `A`, I2:I4 as `B` and J2:J4 as `D`.  Then highlighted E2:E4 and used data validation list and the formula `=INDIRECT($D2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by using the actual Excel app. For whatever reason the in browser version of Excel does not allow for this type of reference. It also has limited paste special options and also doesn't have access to the name manager under formulas tab.
I also did significantly reduce down my formula to `=INDIRECT($D2)` like @ScottCraner suggested.